# Crashes in Skyrim when using AMD Radeon cards in Linux, Steam Proton

Tags: linux, debian, graphics-card, crash, gaming

I have three AMD cards at my disposal which I can use to play games in Debian 10 Linux. All have been recently cleaned and had thermal paste reapplied:

- HD 4870
- HD 5870 - default
- HD 6870

**Problem:**

The 5870 crashes to a grey striped screen when playing Skyrim [original edition, or "Oldrim"]. I have also just started getting crashes on my 6870, which was fine for weeks playing the game. These crashes only happen with Skyrim. The 4870, however, has never crashed when playing the game: I turn all the graphics settings down when using this card apart from the textures which I keep on high.

I am using the non-free AMD Linux firmware from the Debian repo. My PSU is a Corsair VS550 and my [extensive] calculations show it should be fine for the job at load.

**Question:**

I do not know whether this is a software or hardware issue. Would it be worth changing operating system to e.g. Ubuntu 20.04 which uses more up to date graphics drivers? Or is this likely card-related? I have checked temperatures whilst playing and they are all fine.

Note: the crashes on the 6870 only started yesterday after installing Skype. I don't know if that is related. However, I picked the card up on eBay and suspect it's past its best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After switching to Ubuntu 20.04 the problem persists, in fact it took just half an hour for my 5870 to crash in Ubuntu, whereas the 6870 crashed instantly after starting Skyrim.

This points to the 6870 just being past it, and a **very-hard-to-diagnose** hardware bug in the 5870 related to Skyrim [pages and pages exist on this problem on the internet, with no unanimous solution].

On the plus side, performance is smoother with the 4870 in Ubuntu than in Debian, doubtless due to the newer graphics stack and/or kernel.